# Does FirebaseMessagingService run in the background by default?

Tags: android, firebase, android-service, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-intentservice

Does the `FirebaseMessagingService` run in the background similar to how an `IntentService` operates?

I see that `FirebaseMessagingService` extents `Service` which does not run in the background, but I'd like to be sure whether or not I should be doing any work inside the `FirebaseMessagingService` asynchronously or synchronously.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`FirebaseMessagingService`'s method `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)` is called "in the background" (not on the UI/Main thread). If you try do asynchronous work inside `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)` you will receive an error saying:

> Method execute must be called from the main thread, currently inferred thread is worker.

So all work that is done within `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)` should be done synchronously because it's in its own background worker thread.

Comment: There's a side note though: _For all messages where onMessageReceived is provided, your service should handle any message within 10 seconds of receipt. If your app needs more time to process a message, use the Firebase Job Dispatcher._

Comment: @AlécioCarvalho - Definitely, especially with the background restrictions that are in place on the newer versions of Android.

Answer (score 3):

A `Service` does not "run in the background". A `Service` is just an instance of a class (ie: an object). **The methods of a `Service` can run on either the main (UI) thread or on a background (worker) thread**. It all depends on how they are called.

The lifecycle methods of the service `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, `onDestroy()` are all called on the main (UI) thread. But in your `Service` you can start other threads and do other things on those threads.

Comment: Yes that's very true about an android `Service`, but I don't think that's the case when it comes to a `FirebaseMessagingService`. See my answer for more details.