# FirebaseMessagingService onMessageReceived called on main thread?

Tags: android, android-push-notification

Is `FirebaseMessagingService` `onMessageReceived` called on main or background thread?

Comment: Its called on the main thread

Comment: @tyczj How do you know that?

Comment: @tyczj Do you have a link or anything? FirebaseMessagingService derives from Service so I really don't know what it is doing

Comment: You seem to be wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067081/does-firebasemessagingservice-run-in-the-background-by-default

Answer (score 1):

It runs asynchronously with the main thread as it may take some time to download the message which can help in avoiding frozen activity for better user experience.

Comment: It's a `Service`, it runs on the service thread. `FirebaseMessagingService` has it's own process id.

Comment: that still doesn't answer my question whether the `onMessageReceived` is called on main or background thread

Comment: As suggested by Nikola, onMessageRecieved is called by the service when the messge is received. And it runs on separate thread asynchronously which you are referring as background thread.

Comment: Do you have a reference where I can be sure this is how it works?

Comment: @DonBox, checkout my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41067993/2371425

Comment: Thanks @Sakiboy ! If you add an answer here I will mark it as solution

Comment: @DonBox, it’s alright, the other question/answer has been linked in here a couple times, so people will find it. I don’t want to spam or post duplicate answers.